# How to copy contents of <textarea> into a variable with an event listener?

Tags: javascript, textarea, dom-events

I am trying to create a website that allows the user to add custom HTML and CSS in real time. This is easy enough. However, I need to be able to evaluate classes and id(s), so they don't mess with anything. I am using the "input" event listener to detect changes, but it doesn't recognize changes from 'pasting' and 'highlighting + deleting.' What can I do to fix this?

```
let buffer = "";
let new_html = document.getElementsByClassName("insert-new-content");
let preview = document.getElementById("new-content-preview");
let update_html = function (letter){ 

                //Used to recognize when a letter is deleted
                if(!letter.data)buffer = buffer.slice(0, buffer.length - 1);
                //appends new information to buffer for evaluation
                else buffer += letter.data;

};

new_html[0].addEventListener("input", update_html);
new_html[1].addEventListener("input", update_html);
```

Comment: I think pasting should trigger the event. What is `letter.data`?

Comment: You can use the `paste` event to detect that specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`event.srcElement.value;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event#JavaScript). It returns the text of the textarea.

```js
function update_html(event){
  buffer = event.srcElement.value;
}
```